# play2 does not resolve messages when run from a unit test

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm trying to run unit tests for the Play 2 based application, and we are having some issue regarding the Messages. Apparently, this one seams to not properly initialize or not initialized at all.

```
@Test
public void testMessage() throws IOException
{
    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en"));
            String test = Messages.get("test.test");
            System.out.println("DUMMY --" + test);
        }
    });
}
```

The output of the above code is: "DUMMY -- test.test", although I expect the resolved message.

Is there an issue regarding the message? Do we have to load the plugin/messages independently?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will help in your case, but for my codebase I needed to explicitly add the `conf` directory to my classpath to allow tests to access resources from this directory.  In my `Build.scala` file I have:

```
.settings(
  unmanagedClasspath in Compile <+= baseDirectory map { bd => Attributed.blank(bd / "conf") }
)
```