# Play 2.4 Messages object throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, playframework-2.4

This issue occurs in test mode only. Basically I have some calls to Messages.get() in a class being tested

```
Messages.get("api.parser.missing.id")
```

This exists in

```
public long getParserId() throws UnknownParserIdException {
        if (parserEntity == null || parserEntity.parserId == 0) {
            throw new UnknownParserIdException(Messages.get("api.parser.missing.id"));
        }
        return parserEntity.parserId;
    }
```

In my test, I have the following

```
@Test
public void testSaveAndGetParserId() {

    try {
        addParserService.attachAppId(appId);
        addParserService.attachParserJson(jsonToAttach);
        addParserService.transformAttachedJson();
        addParserService.saveParserEntity();
        Long parserId = addParserService.getParserId();
        boolean isPositive = parserId > 0;
        assertTrue(isPositive);
        ParserRepository parserRepository = new ParserRepository();
        parserRepository.deleteParserById(parserId);
    }
    catch (MalformedParserException | UnknownAppIdException | UnknownParserIdException e) {

        assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

Now, whenever I run this test, I get the following NPE

```
[error] Test services.AddParserServiceTest.testTransformNoJsonAttached failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: null, took 0.09 sec
[error]     at play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi.preferred(Messages.scala:482)
[error]     at play.api.i18n.DefaultMessagesApi.preferred(Messages.scala:488)
[error]     at play.i18n.MessagesApi.preferred(MessagesApi.java:128)
[error]     at play.mvc.Http$Context.messages(Http.java:173)
[error]     at play.mvc.Http$Context.lang(Http.java:165)
[error]     at play.i18n.Messages.getLang(Messages.java:29)
[error]     at play.i18n.Messages.get(Messages.java:109)
[error]     at services.impl.AddParserService.transformAttachedJson(AddParserService.java:31)
[error]     at services.AddParserServiceTest.testTransformNoJsonAttached(AddParserServiceTest.java:57)
```

I've got other classes and tests that are not part of my services package that use the il8n classes just fine.

Things I've checked

- The called message does exist in messages
- The messages file is listed in application.conf (which is included by application.test.conf)
- Removing the call to Messages.get() in my service class fixes the NPE, but I don't want to do that obviously.

Comment: You're seven stack frames deep into Play code. Have you stepped into the Play code to see what it is that's null? That would seem to be the place to start.

Comment: Good question. I've honestly never setup a debugger for play, do you have any good materials? That would probably save me a lot of headaches in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only happening while testing your application, it might be due to the fact that your resource file is not accessible in your test folder. Be sure that the file you want to test is in your test folders.

Related post : [play2 does not resolve messages when run from a unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949437/play2-does-not-resolve-messages-when-run-from-a-unit-test)

Comment: It's in the default location in conf. Why would play not be able to read it from there? Putting it in the test root won't fix it.